# change currency output of bdh

Tags: r, bloomberg, rblpapi

How can I set the currency for this to dollars?

```
bdh(securities = "SBMAR1 Comdty", fields = 'PX_LAST', start.date = today() - 10, end.date = today())
```

I tried:

```
bdh(securities = "SBMAR1 Comdty", fields = 'PX_LAST', start.date = today() - 10, end.date = today(), options = c('FX' = 'USD'))
```

> Error in bdh_Impl(con, securities, fields, start.date, end.date, options,  : 
>     Sub-element '(null)' does not exist.

and

```
bdh(securities = "SBMAR1 Comdty", fields = 'PX_LAST', start.date = today() - 10, end.date = today(), options = c('Currency' = 'USD'))
```

> Error in bdh_Impl(con, securities, fields, start.date, end.date, options,  : 
>     Attempt to access unknown sub-element 'Currency' on element 'HistoricalDataRequest'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just has to be lowercase:

```
bdh(securities = "SBMAR1 Comdty", fields = 'PX_LAST', start.date = today() - 10, end.date = today(), options = c("currency"="USD"))
```